# RxJs - Join result of observable with other asynchronous values

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, rxjs, observable

I'm trying to merge 2 object arrays (each one I get from different apis and are of different types). The merge will be done on the last method but first I need to get both lists out of their observables. I need to do something like this:

```
this.result$ = this.firstValues$.pipe(
  function((firstValues) => firstValues.map(firstValue => this.secondApi.fetch(firstValue.id))),
  function((firstValues, secondValues) => this.fillFirstWithSecond(firstValues, secondValues))
);
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT #1:**

The function `this.secondApi.fetch` returns an `Observable<SecondValue>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is quite obtuse. I assume by *function* you mean RxJS operators. In that case, you'd need to make quite a few changes. Although it would be much simpler to also attach a sample input with expected output.

```js
this.result$ = this.firstValues$.pipe(
  switchMap((firstValues) =>
    forkJoin(                         // <-- trigger requests in parallel
      firstValues.map(firstValue =>   // <-- JS `Array#map` function
        this.secondApi.fetch(firstValue.id).pipe(
          map(secondValue => ({       // <-- include the `firstValue` in `secondApi`'s response
            firstValue: firstValue,
            secondValue: secondValue
          }))
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  map((values: {firstValue: any, secondValue: any}[]) => {
    this.fillFirstWithSecond(values.firstValues, values.secondValues)
  })
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much man!! I'd upvote your answer as well but I need 15+ reputation for that.